# Android Flutter how to show data searched in ListView? Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter as well as Android, currently I am doing Search Data from Firestore. I was able to get the data but I couldn't display it on the screen. I'm getting this error

"The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'."

```
_querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['name']
```

And this is the code I'm using for searching

```
 late QuerySnapshot _querySnapshot;

@override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Widget searchedData() {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _querySnapshot.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        _querySnapshot.docs[index].data()['name'],
                        //
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
    
        return LayOut(
          Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: emptyTextSearch),
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                GetBuilder<DataController>(
                    init: DataController(),
                    builder: (val) {
                      return IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          onPressed: () {
                            val.queryData(_searchController.text).then((value) {
                              _querySnapshot = value;
                              setState(() {
                                isExcecuted = true;
                              });
                            });
                          });
                    })
              ],
              title: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search', hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                controller: _searchController,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            body: isExcecuted
                ? searchedData()
                : Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Search any',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        );
       }
```

DataController

```
     class DataController extends GetxController {
      Future getData(String collection) async {
        final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        QuerySnapshot snapshot =
            await firebaseFirestore.collection(collection).get();
        return snapshot.docs;
      }
    
      Future queryData(String queryString) async {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('reports')
            .where('property', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: queryString)
            .get();
      }
    }
```

Please help me get past this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frank's answer should work.

But you can also try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> searchData = _querySnapshot.docs[index].data();
return ListTile(
  title: Text(
    searchData['name'],
  ),
);
```

or

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> searchData = _querySnapshot.docs
.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
print(searchData);
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: searchData.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        searchData[index]['name'],
      ),
    );
});
```

Also, update your code to use stricter types:

```
late QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _querySnapshot;
...
Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryData(String queryString) async {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('reports')
    .where('property', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: queryString)
    .get();
}
```

Comment: I've tried it before, but I'll run into "A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>" in `_querySnapshot.docs[index].data();`

Comment: Okay, try the second option I just added.

Comment: and in your `queryData()`, you should `return await FirebaseFirestore.instance...`. Add await to your queryData() function

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: "type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast" .
Honestly, I've only been learning about Android and Flutter for a while because I have to finish my course. I am more knowledgeable about C# than Flutter, I hope you can help me with this problem

Comment: Yes, I should be able to. Let me run your code and see whats wrong.

Comment: Here I need to replace    `List<Map<String, dynamic>> searchData =
          _querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();`   or `Map<String, dynamic> searchData = _querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList() as Map<String, dynamic>;`

Comment: But strangely when I `add cast` it returns the error "type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

Comment: `List<Map<String, dynamic>> searchData = _querySnapshot.docs.map((e) =>e.data()).toList();` .. I have seen the data returned, but I don't understand why it can't be displayed?

Comment: I just ran your code. I think the problem is from here. Change your querysnapshot to this `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _querySnapshot;`

Comment: Change `late QuerySnapshot _querySnapshot;` to `late QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> _querySnapshot;`

Comment: Yes I changed. And Print show data I finding, but it's not show to screens

Comment: `print(searchData)` has data you need, is there any error message

Comment: No, I didn't see any errors appear

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the additional answer here. In your first snippet, does `Map<String, dynamic> searchData = _querySnapshot.docs[index].data()` somehow perform the cast from `Object` to `Map<String, dynamic>` without needing any operator/keyword?

Comment: Not really, you have to define querySnapshot as `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` (not just `QuerySnapshot`) inorder to cast it from `Object` to `Map<String, dynamic>`. If OP had done this, your answer should have worked.

Answer (score 2):

You're using version 2.0 (or later) of the FlutterFire plugin for Firestore, which requires that you specify the type of a query/snapshot. According to the documentation on [migrating to cloud_firestore 2.0](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration).

The shortest I can think of is:

```
(_querySnapshot.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['name']
```

But if that doesn't work you might need to modify the type of the `val.queryData` that you use her:

```
val.queryData(_searchController.text).then((value) {
```

Your `queryData` returns a `Query` now and that needs to be a `Query<Map<String, dynamic>>`. By changing that the value in `then` becomes a `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`, so that finally `(_querySnapshot.docs[index].data()` becomes a `Map<String, dynamic>`, which is what you need.

Comment: I just updated the DataController, where `queryData` is generated. I tried with your first way, and it doesn't seem to work. In the second way, should I change `queryData` from within my Controller?